# Merge DesiredCapabilities with FirefoxOptions in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium webdriver in C# with a proxy along with some additional properties like below

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.AddArguments("disable-infobars");

String proxyServer= "192.168.1.8:808";
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();

proxy.HttpProxy = proxyServer;
proxy.FtpProxy = proxyServer;
proxy.SslProxy = proxyServer;

DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Proxy, proxy);

var firefoxDriverService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
firefoxDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
```

The Webdriver instance is initialized as

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxDriverService, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600));
```

The only thing I'm not able to do is merge the DesiredCapabilities with FirefoxOptions in order to use proxy. So I want to do something like this

```
options.SetCapability(cap);
```

Is there a way around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `DesiredCapabilities` you can add `Proxy` to `FirefoxOptiions` like this:

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.AddArguments("disable-infobars");

String proxyServer= "192.168.1.8:808";
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();

proxy.HttpProxy = proxyServer;
proxy.FtpProxy = proxyServer;
proxy.SslProxy = proxyServer;

options.Profile.SetProxyPreferences(proxy); //this line is crucial
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.Proxy, proxy);`?

From the [source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Firefox/FirefoxOptions.cs):

```
public class FirefoxOptions : DriverOptions
...
        /// <summary>
        /// Provides a means to add additional capabilities not yet added as type safe options
        /// for the Firefox driver.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="optionName">The name of the capability to add.</param>
        /// <param name="optionValue">The value of the capability to add.</param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentException">
        /// thrown when attempting to add a capability for which there is already a type safe option, or
        /// when <paramref name="optionName"/> is <see langword="null"/> or the empty string.
        /// </exception>
        /// <remarks>Calling <see cref="AddAdditionalFirefoxOption(string, object)"/>
        /// where <paramref name="optionName"/> has already been added will overwrite the
        /// existing value with the new value in <paramref name="optionValue"/>.
        /// Calling this method adds capabilities to the Firefox-specific options object passed to
        /// geckodriver.exe (property name 'moz:firefoxOptions').</remarks>
        public void AddAdditionalFirefoxOption(string optionName, object optionValue)
        {
            this.ValidateCapabilityName(optionName);
            this.additionalFirefoxOptions[optionName] = optionValue;
        }
...
```

Comment: I would expect attempts to use `AddAdditionalCapability` with a capability name of “proxy” to throw an exception, as it should when you attempt to use a known capability name.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is using the standard `Proxy` type to set the proxy settings for the instance of Firefox that is instantiated, modern versions of the .NET bindings provide a `FirefoxOptions.Proxy` property, which would be integrated into your code as follows:

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.AddArguments("disable-infobars");

String proxyServer= "192.168.1.8:808";
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();

proxy.HttpProxy = proxyServer;
proxy.FtpProxy = proxyServer;
proxy.SslProxy = proxyServer;

options.Proxy = proxy;

var firefoxDriverService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
firefoxDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxDriverService, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600));
```

There should be no need to set the proxy properties in the user profile, as in the accepted answer.

Comment: Is there a way in Visual Studio to manage a proxy within the app or do you have to set something up separately?  I see some random stuff about setting up a proxy with Selenium but nothing about the actual proxy server itself.  Almost makes it look like the proxy server is part of Selenium and launches on it's own or something.  I'm trying to use Selenium to monitor all traffic that exists loading a website to find specific URLs being loaded that contain certain words.

Comment: The proxy server will be a separate project from Selenium. I have written [several](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2013/08/implementing-webdriver-http-status.html) [blog](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2013/09/capturing-javascript-errors-in.html) [posts](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2019/05/handling-authentication-requests-with.html) about using a proxy in C#, using a couple of different software proxies.